# Cannot perform unit test with function which have createCriteria() statement

Tags: groovy, createcriteria, unit-testing

I want to write a unit test (by JUnit) to test value of this function in Groovy:

```
    String getPeopleNamesById(int[] peopleIds) {
        List<String> names = People.createCriteria().list{
            projections { property("name") }
            'in' ("id", peopleIds)
        }
        return names ? names.join(", ") : "";
    }
```

But the unit test always fails when reading this statement: List names = People.createCriteria().list{...}
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: People.createCriteria() is applicable for argument types: () values: [].
I guess it because of calling to functions which execute some DB connections and queries?
Could you please help me write this test? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criteria queries aren't available in unit tests, and aren't provided by `mockDomain`.  You can either mock your criteria queries yourself, e.g. with `mockFor`, or make your test an integration test, where you have access to a full database environment.

Here's an example of how you could mock your query:

```
mockFor(People).demand.static.createCriteria = { ->
    [list: { closure -> [ <some mock objects> ] } ]
}
```